# while selecting sunday date it select date of next week

Tags: ios, iphone

Hi i'm using this code for getting start date and end date of  week. But if i select Sunday it moves on next week and gives me result in next week.

Please suggest how i can get appropriate result by selecting Sunday date.

thanks in advance.

```
NSDate *today = date;
NSLog(@"Today date is %@",today);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];// you can use your  format.

//Week Start Date

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:today];

NSInteger dayofweek = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:today] weekday];// this will give you current day of week

[components setDay:([components day] - ((dayofweek) - 2))];// for beginning of the week.

NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat_first = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat_first setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString  *dateString2Prev = [dateFormat stringFromDate:beginningOfWeek];

NSDate *weekstartPrev = [dateFormat_first dateFromString:dateString2Prev];

//  NSDate *weekEndPrev = [dateFormat_End dateFromString:dateEndPrev];
NSDateFormatter *dateFf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFf setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
strStartDate = [dateFf stringFromDate:weekstartPrev];

NSLog(@"%@",strStartDate);


//Week End Date

NSCalendar *gregorianEnd = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];


NSDateComponents *componentsEnd = [gregorian components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:today];

NSInteger Enddayofweek = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:today] weekday];// this will give you current day of week

[componentsEnd setDay:([componentsEnd day]+(7-Enddayofweek)+1)];// for end day of the week

NSDate *EndOfWeek = [gregorianEnd dateFromComponents:componentsEnd];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat_End = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat_End setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateEndPrev = [dateFormat stringFromDate:EndOfWeek];

NSDate *weekEndPrev = [dateFormat_End dateFromString:dateEndPrev];
NSDateFormatter *dateF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateF setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
strEndDate = [dateF stringFromDate:weekEndPrev];

NSString *showStartDate = [self setAPIDateFormat:weekstartPrev:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];
NSString *showEndDate =[self setAPIDateFormat:weekEndPrev:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];

_lblStartEnd.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  -  %@",showStartDate,showEndDate];

datesArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


// NSDate *startD = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: -86400.0];

datesArray = [self getDatesArrayBetweenTwoDates:[weekstartPrevdateByAddingTimeInterval: -86400.0] andEndDate:weekEndPrev];

[_Workdiscription reloadData];
```

Comment: There is far too much code here. Which bit of code is the bit that is going wrong? Also, you have a lot of duplicated code here... `gregorian` and `gregorianEnd` are the same calendar. `components` and `componentsEnd` are the same etc...

Comment: It sounds like you are using an "American" calendar. Their weeks start on Sundays.

Comment: Weeks start on Sunday by default, try setting first weekday of your calendar to 2 (1=Sunday,2=Monday,...) or change calendar locale

Comment: @Fogmeister I think this line convert  it back date       NSString  *dateString2Prev = [dateFormat stringFromDate:beginningOfWeek];